# What does this sentence exactly imply?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a sentence in a book, Word Power Made Easy, which was:

> Sometime in your dim past, you were crossed, scorned and deeply wounded by a woman (a mother, or mother figure, perhaps?). So now you have a carefully constructed defence against further  hurt - you hate all women.

Does it mean that the "you" has started hating all the women including his mother just because she once scorned him. I am asking this because I don't think anybody would start hating his or her mother just because she once scorned them.

I know this is less of an English question if anything. But I'm asking this because I suspect my understanding of the text could also be wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should any article precede "mother" in this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/212543/should-any-article-precede-mother-in-this-sentence)

Answer (score -1):

> Does it mean that the "you" has started hating all the women including his mother just because she once scorned him.

Is almost correct. You added "once": "she **once** scorned him". Without "once", your understanding would be very correct, because the bad things <strike>actually</strike> might have happened many times.

Comment: @virolino- Remember that there is "sometime" in the starting of the sentence. So the act must have happened only once.

Comment: You are right about the number of "required" occurrences, I updated the answer.

Comment: @Kevin: "sometime" is not necessarily identical with "at one specific moment in time". It can refer to some period of time - when one action could repeat for a number of times.